# updatePanel set async type request

Tags: updatepanel

How set Type UpdatePanel To Async.

for this User  that Continue work to page.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand well your question because of a lack of information, but did you know an update panel is asynchronous itself?

UpdatePanel is an ASP.NET AJAX control that lets some part of your page to be partially-rendered, meaning it can be updated without a full-postback.

If you want to do other asynchronous things, you may need to use more than an UpdatePanel, or leverage ASP.NET Callback API, or just use jQuery/AJAX.

Perhaps you've a single update panel that updates the entire page... If this is true, why you'd want to use UpdatePanel? :)

Comment: how leverage ASP.NET Callback API,Work it

Comment: haha, you need to learn it! Check this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx